# Downloading files. Network problems causes corrupt files

Tags: c#, .net, download, httpwebrequest

My application downloads huge files using `HttpWebRequest -> WebResponse -> Stream -> FileStream`. See code below.

With following the scenario we always get corrupted files:

1. Start download.
2. Unplug cable or click to pause download process.
3. Close and open the application.
4. Start download (it starts from the interruption point).
5. Wait full file is downloaded.

Problem: the downloaded file is corrupted.

I'm sure this is common problem, but I failed googling or SOing it. Please advise. What can be the cause?

```
public class Downloader
{
    int StartPosition { get; set; }
    int EndPosition { get; set; }
    bool Cancelling { get; set; }

    void Download(string[] args)
    {
        string uri = @"http://www.example.com/hugefile.zip";
        string localFile = @"c:\hugefile.zip";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.AddRange(this.StartPosition);
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Stream inputStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(localFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            int buffSize = 8192;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[buffSize];
            int readSize;

            do
            {
                // reads the buffer from input stream
                readSize = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffSize);

                fileStream.Position = this.StartPosition;
                fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, (int)readSize);
                fileStream.Flush();

                // increase the start position
                this.StartPosition += readSize;

                // check if the stream has reached its end
                if (this.EndPosition > 0 && this.StartPosition >= this.EndPosition)
                {
                    this.StartPosition = this.EndPosition;
                    break;
                }

                // check if the user have requested to pause the download
                if (this.Cancelling)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            while (readSize > 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you compare the 2 files what are the differences? Is the downloaded one missing a section? Does it have a duplicated section or does it have an incorrect section?

Comment: Wow! I had to do that first before asking the question. Files are binary. How to do comparison of two binary files?

Comment: The trial version of Beyond Compare should do what you need.

Comment: Could you please make first you comment as the answer? Because it is the correct answer. The Beyond Compare tool showed that the server was broken, did not supported the Accept-Ranges header. Thanks, Martin!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To troubleshoot this I would suggest doing a file compare to determine what the differences are. Is the downloaded one missing a section? Does it have a duplicated section or does it have an incorrect section?

Comment: The Beyond Compare tool showed that the server was broken, did not supported the Accept-Ranges header. Thanks, Martin!

Answer (score 1):

The AddRange() call is wrong, you want to pass a negative value so you'll get the remainder of the file.  From the MSDN Library article:

*If range is positive, the range is from the start of the data to range.*
*If range is negative, the range is from range to the end of the data.*

I can't see how EndPosition is being initialized, that could be wrong too.

Comment: I'm aware of that problem and I handle it in the real code. The code here is not the real one. It is stripped. Thanks.

Comment: No idea what that means.  But the AddRange call is definitely wrong and explains the corruption.

Comment: Actually you have specified wrong.
It is like: If range is positive, the range parameter specifies the starting point of the range. The server should start sending data from the range parameter specified to the end of the data in the HTTP entity.

If range is negative, the range parameter specifies the ending point of the range. The server should start sending data from the start of the data in the HTTP entity to the range parameter specified.


source: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992002%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)